# How to send styled data from text editor to mongoDB?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, react-draft-wysiwyg

I am not able to get that how can I send styled data from text editor in React to MongoDB and then how to get back the same styled data to the frontend for eg. In a blog, users submit a blog description by applying some styles to the text and I want the text to be stored with the same style to MongoDB i.e. Database, and then show the same styles to the blog list on the frontend.

PS: Pardon my English

Comment: How does your "styled data" look like?

Comment: Please add more example what you mean by "styled data" is it html?

Comment: Styled data means bold, colored, italic, etc. styles to text i.e. Html data created by text-editor

Comment: The text should be returned exactly the way it was sent.   Has the formatting code been stripped from the return?  What formatting code is being used?

Comment: You didn't mention it in your question, but you did add the tag `react-draft-wysiwyg`, is that the source for the text?  How are you retrieving the text from the widget to send to mongodb?

Comment: I want to know whole procedure which includes sending data from frontend to backend and then retrieving it back.